# F# inferred types in If/Then

Tags: f#, type-inference, unit-type

If I have the following function:

```
let myFunc x y =
  if y = 0 then 1
  x
```

I get the error:

```
Program.fs(58,17): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    unit    
but here has type
    int
```

Why does the compiler expect 'unit' instead of int ?

Comment: The fact that you tagged this as `if-statement` is telling -- in F#, `if` is an _expression_. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn While F# might consider `if` an *expression*, other languages do not.  Having a tag just for F#'s understanding of `if` may cause others a great deal of confusion...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might worth adding that this is not just a property of `if`. F# is an expression-based language meaning that pretty much every piece of code (aside from type declarations and a few exceptions) is an *expression* that evaluates to some result. In fact, F# does not call `if` the if *statement*, but an if *expression*.

This means that you can use `if` in unexpected places. For example, this might be useful:

```
x/2 + (if x%2=0 then 0 else 1)
```

As already explained by Garry, if you omit `else`, then the expression still needs to return something - if the result was to be an `int`, then it would not really make sense (which number should the compiler pick?), so it requires that the result is of type `unit`, which is a special type representing "no result".

The `unit` type is also the result of all imperative functions (e.g. `printf`) or of all expressions that do not logically return any value (assignment or e.g. loop). This means that if you write:

```
if x > 0 then printfn "Big!"
```

... then the expression is well-typed, because `printfn "Big!"` has a return type `unit` and the implicitly added `else` branch also returns `unit`. You can create a value of type `unit` directly by hand (the type has exactly one value), so the above actually corresponds to:

```
if x > 0 then printfn "Big!" else ()
```

From the C# perspective, it makes more sense to read `if .. then .. else` as the conditional operator:

```
x/2 + (x%2 == 0 ? 0 : 1)
```

Answer (score 7):

In F# when using an `if` statement when there is no `else` branch then it implicitly returns `unit`. If your `then` branch returns a type other than `unit` you must have an explicit `else` branch for it to work correctly. In your example you could write:

```
let myFunc x y = if y = 0 then 1 else x
```

MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233231.aspx