# if requires an else clause

Tags: f#, semantics

I have essentially the following code in a function, and I would like to eliminate the duplication of `doSomethingElse()`:

```
fun a ->
    if a = b then
        let c = expensiveOperation()
        if c = d then
            result
        else
            doSomethingElse()
    else
        doSomethingElse()
```

I think I should be able to eliminate both else clauses. and let it return either `result` or `doSomethingElse()`. When I do that, the error message from the compiler is: "This expression was expected to have type     unit     but here has type     int        "

Why does the `if` expression require the `else` clause?

Comment: This question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16490473/701062

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to what you wrote, but I wonder if you mean something else.

```
if a = b && expensiveOperation() = d then result
else doSomethingElse()
```

Comment: The goal was to avoid `expensiveOperation()` and I wasn't thinking about the shortcut of the boolean expressions. We will only evaluate the rhs of the `&&` `if a = b`, so I can do just what you suggest.